# Variable scope, immutable vs mutable, in terms of +=

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a follow up question to [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use).

case-1, the following code

```
a = 0
def test_immutable():
    a += 1
test_immutable()
```

encounters an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Answers to the original post explains the first case well. `a += 1` makes an assignment, and so makes `a` a local variable that has not been assigned with any object yet, and therefore referencing it causes the `UnboundLocalError`.

When I replace `a` with `array[0]` in the second example below, it works without `UnboundLocalError`.

case-2, the following code

```
array = [0, 0, 0]
def test_mutable():
    array[0] += 1
test_mutable()
print(array)
```

outputs

```
[1, 0, 0]
```

I guess it has something to do with `a` being immutable while `array` being mutable. But how exactly does Python treat the two cases differently? I'm confused.

Comment: It's not an issue of mutability, it's the fact that you are not rebinding the name `array` to something else. `array` points to the same object before, during, and after your function. If you tried: `array += [1]` you would get the same error.

Comment: Just as a general note, the rules of variable binding like this are very confusing until you get a good feel for them, but I promise it starts to come naturally once you've played with it enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are observing does not really have anything to do with mutable or immutable types, it is a scoping issue.

Consider, the following:

```py
a = 0
a += 1
```

This works although `0` is immutable.

Also, this:

```py
array = [0, 0, 0]
def test_mutable():
    array += [1]

test_mutable()
print(array)
```

does throw you the same `UnboundLocalError`.

The issue is with scoping. When you try to re-use `a` inside a function, the interpreter sorts of gets confused at which `a` you are meaning, because it first realizes that whatever you want to compute, you want to have it with the name `a`, so it reserves the local name `a` for you, overriding the global `a`, but then when you try to use it for the `+= 1` bit, it realizes that there is nothing bound to the local `a`.

With the `array`, and specifically with `array[0]` the situation is different as you are not reserving the name `array` for local use, but just keep on using the global `array`.

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you norok2. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When a global variable is updated in a function like in your case, it should be explicitly be declared as global and this would work fine.

```
a = 0
def test_immutable():
    global a
    a += 1
test_immutable()
```

So the case when you were getting an error, it was assuming `a` as a local variable but there was no declaration before updating it, i.e., `a+=1`.  If you are not updating a global variable in your function, you can use the global variable without explicitly declaring it as global. For example:

```
a = 0
def test_immutable():
    print(a)
test_immutable()
```

In the case of a list, you are not updating the whole list, rather updating an element of it. Therefore, it should work without explicitly declaring it as global.

If you try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
def test_immutable():
    a = [1, 4, 3]
test_immutable()
print(a)
```

The output would be `[1, 2, 3]` since the array is getting updated in a local reference. However, if you try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
def test_immutable():
    global a
    a = [1, 4, 3]
test_immutable()
print(a)
```

The output would be `[1, 4, 3]` because values are getting updated in global reference and without any error.