# scope rules for lists: assignment statements and UnboundedLocalErrors

Tags: python

this is a follow up question to [Variable scope, immutable vs mutable, in terms of +=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023327/variable-scope-immutable-vs-mutable-in-terms-of).

```
def update():
    L.extend([1])
L=[1,2,3]
update()
print(L)
```

outputs `[1,2,3,1]`

but

```
def update1():
    L=L+[1]
L=[1,2,3]
update1()
print(L)
```

outputs `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L' referenced before assignment`

but

```
def update2():
    L[0]=L[0]+1
L=[1,2,3]
update2()
print(L)
```

outputs `[2,2,3]`

i understand that `update1()` produces an UnboundLocalError because, when an assignment to L is made inside `update1()`, python marks L as a local variable with no assigned value. so `L+=[1]` gives an error, since a variable is being read before being assigned.(And this is also why "you cannot modify a variable defined outside the current scope")

And i understand that `update()` works because no assignment to L was made, so python did not create a local variable L( with no assigned value). hence, according to the LEGB rule, the extend method is then applied to global variable L.

But i do not understand why `update2()` works.
I was thinking that one or all of the following things could happen

1. python can give a syntax error, or maybe a type `error()`  (since `L[0]` is not a valid variable name)
2. python can give a type error, if L gets marked as a local variable with no assigned value.
3. `UnboundedLocalError`

but it is none of the above

Should it (`update2()`) be considered as an exception, or is there an explanation behind why `update(2)` works the way it does?

Comment: `L[0] = foo` becomes `L.__setitem__(0, foo)` - you're just looking up an attribute (like `extend`) on `L`, not trying to assign to that identifier.

Comment: You were partially right. L is a name that references some object. When you do `L=`, you assign something to the name. However, when you do L[0], you don't change the object that L references, you modify insides - it literally looks up the object, then changes whatever item was at 0th index. At this point the name doesn't matter, eg you could've done `A=L; A[0]+=1` - L would be changed anyway, because they reference the same object, but A is a local variable.